# To split the string into two in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My XML source looks like:

```
<span class="char-style-override-6">Breast Problems (Female and Male)   511</span>
```

and I have a template match for it

```
<xsl:template match="span" mode="table">
```

My difficulty now is within this template match, I need to create two  tags, the first will contain the string "Breast Problems (Female and Male)", while the second  only contain the page number "511".

I just don't know how to do this substring split, in order to differentiate text and numeric value.

Comment: Are you able to use XSTL/XPath 2.0?  If so, Christopher's answer is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="table"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="span" mode="table">
        <xsl:variable name="split" select="replace(., '.*\s(\d+)$', '$1')"/>
        <string><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(., $split))"/></string>
        <number><xsl:value-of select="$split" /></number>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <span class="char-style-override-6">Breast Problems (Female and Male)   511</span>
</root>
```

gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <string>Breast Problems (Female and Male)</string>
    <number>511</number>
</output>
```

Answer (score 3):

**In XSLT 1.0 use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="span">
  <xsl:variable name="vNumeric" select=
  "translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNonNumeric" select=
   "normalize-space(substring-before(., $vNumeric))"/>

  <nonNumeric><xsl:value-of select="$vNonNumeric"/></nonNumeric>
  <numeric><xsl:value-of select="$vNumeric"/></numeric>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<span class="char-style-override-6">Breast Problems (Female and Male)   511</span>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<nonNumeric>511</nonNumeric>
<numeric>Breast Problems (Female and Male)</numeric>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The *double translate method*.
2. Appropriate use of `substring-before()` and `normalize-space()`.

Comment: I like the double translate idea! What I don't like is that when there is any additional digit in the span element outside of the final number, then the result is not correct (no string value in output, all digits concatenated) while mine is correct. By the way you inadvertently swapped num and nonNum in your stylesheet.

Comment: @Maestro13: Thanks for noticing this -- fixed. As for more than one number, in such case the problem as defined by the OP becomes meaningless -- there is no more a clear *split* between a *non-numeric* part and *numeric* part -- as per his description.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tokenize: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

If you know all of your nodes are delimited by three spaces, that may be a good way to go, or you could use a regular expression and work backwards from the end of the node content.

Comment: `tokenize()` is only valid for XSTL/XPath 2.0, which was never stated, and still may be valid.