# XPath to return part of a string

Tags: xml, xpath

hope someone can advise me here with my XPath query. I want to extract and display part of a string but the result that I am getting at the moment is returning the full string.
I want to be able to get two results like the ones below.

```
<airline>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-arrival-date-0101">01</flight-number>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-arrival-date-0102">02</flight-number>
</airline>
```

This is the xml file flights.xml that I am working with.

```
<airline>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102">01–02</flight-number>
</airline>
```

For example, I just get 01-02 as my result when I try this XPath query below but more needs to be done to get what I stated above. I want the strings for 01 and 02 to be returned separately.
`/airline/flight-number/child::text()`

Can someone advise me on how to achieve the results with XPath for what I am trying to do?

Comment: you want the value of the flight_id attribute and the flight number?  Please show exactly what you are wanting as the expected output.  It is not clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To split the string into two in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623976/to-split-the-string-into-two-in-xpath)

Comment: What I want to achieve is to turn this ```<airline>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102">01–02</flight-number>
</airline>``` into this one ```<airline>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-arrival-date-0101">01</flight-number>
    <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-arrival-date-0102">02</flight-number>
</airline>``` I want to do it with XPath.

Comment: Xpath it's a query language, won't create elements as requested in the question so another language should be used for that.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a way that I can query it with XPath to get the 01 0r 02 value instead of getting 01-02 together? All my attempts so far always return 01-02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to get two results like the ones below

With [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet), for example:

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  --var fn '//flight-number[@flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102"]' \
  -a '$fn' -t elem -n 'flight-number' \
  -u '$prev' -x '$fn/node() | $fn/@*' \
  -u '$prev/text()' -x 'substring-after(.,"–")' \
  -u '$fn/text()' -x 'substring-before(.,"–")' \
file.xml
```

- `--var` keeps the relevant node in a variable named `fn`
- `-a …` appends an empty same-named sibling node
- the `$prev` (aka `$xstar:prev`) variable refers to the node created
  by the most recent `-i (--insert)`, `-a (--append)`, or `-s (--subnode)`
  option; examples of `$prev` are given in
  [doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
- 1st `-u …` makes the new sibling a duplicate of `$fn`, copying its
  child and attribute nodes
- 2nd `-u …` updates the text of the new sibling node
- 3rd `-u …` updates the text of the original node
- the XPath 1.0 string functions are documented
  [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116.html#section-String-Functions),
  the user's guide for `xmlstarlet edit` is
  [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html)

Output:

```xml
<airline>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102">01</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102">02</flight-number>
</airline>
```

---

**UPDATE** 2022-09-25

If input contains a series of flights then each can get a sibling node
like this,

```sh
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  --var fln '//flight-number' \
  -a '$fln' -t elem -n 'flight-number' \
  --var sib '$fln/following-sibling::*[position() mod 2 = 1]' \
  -u '$sib' -x 'preceding-sibling::*[1]/node() | preceding-sibling::*[1]/@*' \
  -u '$fln/text()' -x 'substring-before(.,"-")' \
  -u '$sib/text()' -x 'substring-after(.,"-")' \
file.xml
```

where variable `sib` references the siblings that are interleaved.

Sample output:

```xml
<airline>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-0102">01</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-0102">02</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-123456-0910">09</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-123456-0910">10</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-789012-3031">30</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-789012-3031">31</flight-number>
</airline>
```

(**end** update)

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet` and `bash`:

```bash
alias xml=xmlstarlet
f1=$( xml sel -t -m 'airline/flight-number' -v 'substring-before(., "-")' infile.xml)
f2=$( xml sel -t -m 'airline/flight-number' -v 'substring-after (., "-")' infile.xml)
fid=$(xml sel -t -m 'airline/flight-number/@flight_id'               \
                 -v 'substring(., 1, string-length(.)-2)' infile.xml)

xml ed -d airline/flight-number infile.xml                           |
xml ed -s airline -type elem -n flight-number -v $f1                 |
xml ed -s airline -type elem -n flight-number -v $f2                 |
xml ed -a 'airline/flight-number[1]' -t attr -n flight_id -v $fid$f1 |
xml ed -a 'airline/flight-number[2]' -t attr -n flight_id -v $fid$f2
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<airline>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0101">01</flight-number>
  <flight-number flight_id="flt-888712-departure-date-arrival-date-0102">02</flight-number>
</airline>
```